# I load my variable to the dataframe using loop but it only print last varibles store in data all others variable are discarded

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I try to load my data from a CSV file using the code below. For some reason it isn't working correctly, because it only load the last loop variables values...

```
import csv
import newspaper
import pandas as pd
from newspaper import Article
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['txt','date1','authors1'])
lista = ['https://www.dawn.com/news/1643189','https://www.dawn.com/news/1648926/former-pakistan-captain-inzamamul-haq-suffers-heart-attack-in-lahore']
    
for list in lista:
    
    first_article = Article(url="%s" % list, language='de')
    first_article.download()
    first_article.parse()
    txt = first_article.text
    date1 = first_article.publish_date
    authors1 = first_article.authors
    data = [[txt,date1,authors1]]
    data = [[txt,date1,authors1]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['txt','date1','authors1'])
    df.to_csv('pagedata.csv')
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('pagedata.csv')` overwrites the file on each iteration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design!  You are overwriting your output.  Try something like:

```py
f = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['txt','date1','authors1'])
lista = ['https://www.dawn.com/news/1643189','https://www.dawn.com/news/1648926/former-pakistan-captain-inzamamul-haq-suffers-heart-attack-in-lahore']

for i, list in enumerate(lista):

   first_article = Article(url="%s" % list, language='de')
   first_article.download()
   first_article.parse()
   txt = first_article.text
   date1 = first_article.publish_date
   authors1 = first_article.authors
   data = [[txt,date1,authors1]]
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['txt','date1','authors1'])
   df.to_csv(f"page_{i}_data.csv2")
```

**edit:** apparently you want to collate your data.  Something like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['txt','date1','authors1'])
for row in lista:

   first_article = Article(url=row, language='en')
   first_article.download()
   first_article.parse()
   txt = first_article.text
   date1 = first_article.publish_date
   author1 = first_article.authors
   df.loc[len(df.index)] = [txt, date1, authors1]


df.to_csv("pagedata.csv2")
```

The main thing is having a variable *outside* the loop you can append to.

Note that I have corrected the language (these articles are in English, not German), and removed a redundant string replace (`url="%s" % url == url=url`).

Comment: it will give me 2 CSV files but I want data in one file with a proper data frame. for example in each iteration, it will store data in the same file with creating a new row. data store in column-wise as name the column (txt, date1, authors1). the text data store in text column and date store in date column and so on...

Comment: Ah! you didn't exactly say that in the question....

Comment: yes, I think soo.. hope so now you help me out thanks

Comment: the edited program give dataless dataframe

Comment: @khawarmaqsood apologies, I don't use Pandas very much and naively thought I could append to it and it would do the right thing.  I have now *run* the answer and it works.  the principle is the same however: keep a var *outside* your loop and append to that.